# No compiling and running errors, but red underlines below....Why?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

A very very strange question troubing me——I get everything right in VS：

[image]
However I met with problems while opening the file, with the red underlines below.....

[image]

Any one knows why? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a plugin issue, if so try and run visual studio in safe mode (as this disables all plugins). If there are no longer any underlines then it is likely one of your plugins, resharper being a common culprit.

To run it in safe mode open the visual studio command prompt and type in:

```
devenv /Safemode
```

Other times your intellisense just gets 'stuck'. Try switching your build configuration from Debug -> Release and then back again.

You can also try deleting your intellisense index file. Close Visual studio and the file will be the in the same folder as your solution and will be called `SolutionName.sdf`. Then reopen visual studio and your solution, it will begin re-indexing the intellisense for your solution.

Failing all that try deleting your `\bin` and `\obj` directories. These usually cause issues if you're working on a project that was made in an older version of Visual Studio.